# Parsing curl response

Tags: php, parsing, curl

i'm using **curl** to retrieve a page which has a table structure as below.
  ...

```
  <tr>
        <td>
             <table>table1</table>
             <table>table2</table>
             ....................
             <table>table25</table>
        </td>
  </tr>
```

....
 i need the data in table *table1* to *table 25*. How to parse it to get the data.(which is curl response)

**Note: table1 to 25 doesn't have id and name**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Parse HTML With PHP And DOM](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html).

Whatever you do, don't start concocting convoluted regular expressions to parse it.